# How to implement tap event on ImageCell in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using `ImageCell` inside `TableView` to create various setting page.

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection>
            <ImageCell x:Name="darkTheme" Text="Dark theme" />
            <ImageCell x:Name="lightTheme" Text="Light theme" />
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

In my C# code I have the following:

```
lightTheme.Tapped += new EventHandler((e, s) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Light theme tapped");
});
```

It's not being triggered everytime I tapped the image cell. Anyone knows how to properly implement a tap event in an `ImageCell` just like the `TapGestureRecognizer` in a `ViewCell`?

Comment: This should work as intended. Just tested on the Android emulator (API 23), and on iOS, and it works properly there. Which device/API level are you testing on?

Comment: Testing this on iOS (iPhone 7+)

Comment: Only thing I can think of why this may not work, is that it might have something to do with touch pressure (Force Touch). Not sure though. Does it work when you use Gerald's answer?

Comment: Unfortunately Gerald's answer is giving me an error (please refer to my reply to him).

Comment: Also just tried testing on iPhone 6+ still not working

Comment: My bad, you cannot hook up GestureRecognizer to cells. You would have to implement your own Cell to do this. Why is the tapped event not always working according to you?

Comment: Exactly, the `GestureRecognizers` property is only available on controls that inherit from `View`, but `ImageCell` inherits from `Cell`, which in turn inherits from `Element` instead of `View`. I think the core question is why this is not working on your environment. How often is it not triggered and how are you testing exactly?

Comment: @TimKlingeleers it is never triggered at all. Im testing this on a physical device as well as the simulators.

Comment: Oh, not at all? Very odd. You are running in debug mode right?  Does it work on Android?

Comment: Yeah running on debug mode with breakpoints and all. I haven't tried on Android though as for now I'm working on the iOS side.

Comment: Last thing you can try to rule out some debug issues, try to show an alert like this: `DisplayAlert("Test", "Test", "OK");`. If that doesn't show either, I'm out of options for now.

Comment: @TimKlingeleers thanks for patiently answering my queries. I have tried that already as well. It basically just not triggering the tapped event. It's frustrating :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143030/discussion-between-tim-klingeleers-and-iamsophia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathered from the extensive comments and chat I see that you had a custom renderer for the `TableView` in place. This renderer on iOS had the property `AllowSelection` set to false, effectively stopping you from selecting a cell and thus causing the tapped event not to be fired.

I just thought I'd put it up as a solution for future reference.

Comment: That is indeed the issue. :-)